# How to set text into a DOM element

Tags: python, xml, dom, svg, minidom

I'm trying to set text into a DOM element. I create the element.

```
svg_doc = minidom.parse('PATH_TO_SVG_FILE.svg')
category = svg_doc.createElement('category')
```

Then I try to set the `nodeValue`:

```
category.nodeValue = 'Design'
```

But I get:

```
<category/>
```

instead of:

```
<category>Design<category/>
```

How to get the desired result with minidom?

Comment: Are you trying to add a text into that element? `txt = dom.createTextNode("Design")`. Then append to the category element: `category.appendChild(txt)`

Comment: I try to get this: `<category>Design<category/>`. Sorry I forgot the code markup before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
category.createTextNode('Design')
```

See: https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html